# make single Bundle project using Bootstrapper in Window installer XML

Tags: wix, outlook-addin, bootstrapper, wix3.7

i have done a project for outlook add-ins. then i used WIX to create a setup file for this add-ins. But we need resolve the dependencies too, so i made a bootstrappper project using wix, which first check for the dependencies and then install add-ins using the setup file. it works good.
**Problem**
is there any way to merge these two setup project into single project. ?
here is my code for bootstrapper.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Bundle Name="OutlookReport" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Tzunami" UpgradeCode="93597211-ba8c-44f0-9f73-18e7afc47d85">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="Resource\\EULA.rtf" LogoFile="Resource\\TzunamiLogo.png"
                                              SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2010" Guid="CFF13DD8-6EF2-49EB-B265-E3BFC6501C1D" Variable="Outlook2010"/>
    <util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2010PIA" Guid="1D844339-3DAE-413E-BC13-62D6A52816B2" Variable="Outlook2010PIA"/>
    <util:ComponentSearch Id="SearchOutlook2013" Guid="F9F828D5-9F0B-46F9-9E3E-9C59F3C5E136" Variable="Outlook2013"/>
    <bal:Condition Message="This Setup need Outlook 2010 or 2013 to be installed">
      Outlook2010 OR Outlook2010PIA OR Outlook2013
    </bal:Condition>

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeTest" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="VSTORFeature_CLR40" Variable="VSTORFeature"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4R" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4R"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4"/>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"/>
      <ExePackage Id="Downloading_Microsoft_VSTORuntime" SourceFile="Resource\\vstor_redist.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no"
                  DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                  DetectCondition="VSTORFeature"
                  InstallCondition="NOT VSTORFeature OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4R >=v10.0.40303) OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4 >=v10.0.21022)" />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupOutlookReports.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" Id="OutlookReports" />
    </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: This is not typically done and would take some work. Why?

Comment: my boss wants me to make merge these setup file in a single setup file. i tried it too but failed to do so, cause there is no way to add the vsto (output of Add-ins) in Bootstrapper's chain. 

if there is any ways please suggest me what kind of work i have to do to achieve it. 
Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think I misunderstood. I was thinking you wanted to rewrite two .wixproj files into one .wixproj file. Do you mean that you want vstor_redist.exe embedded in the bootstrapper .exe like the .msi is? Please explain your the outcome you desire more fully.

Comment: you were right. i want to merge these two .wixproj into single project, not those setup files like vstor_redist.exe. is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Is this an [XY-Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? A WiX bootstrapper is—by design—a separate project, unlike the [Visual Studio Bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294(v=vs.100).aspx) that some may be used to. Is your issue really with how a WiX bootstrapper installs things? E.G. Creates an Add/Remove Programs entry for the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain in one bootstrapper inside other. Just modify Compressed="no" to Compressed="yes" in your exepackage, This will embed it in current project.

Comment: thanks for reply but this is not what i want. i want to merge these two .wixproj into single .wixproj project.